# Is this a valid norm?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

For a positive semidefinite invertible matrix X define the following quantity over the set of  symmetric matrices M

$$f_X(M) = \sqrt{Trace(XM^2)}$$

Is $f_X(M)$ a valid norm? If yes is it easy to show that the dual norm is the norm corresponding to $f_{X^{-1}}(M)$ ?

Comment: You already don't have $f_X(\lambda M)=|\lambda|f_X(M)$...

Comment: My bad. I had a typo which I have fixed now. The version earlier wont satisfy triangle inequalities also.

Comment: writing positive semidefinite and invertible is really irritating. **it is a norm on the space of real symmetric matrices**. it is just a weighted Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the meaning of "matrix norm". In linear algebra literature, a "matrix norm" usually refers to a submultiplicative norm, but in other areas of mathematics, submultiplicativity is not an implicit assumption.

**Edit.** Your definition of $f_X(M)$ can be extended to cover  $M_n(\mathbb R)$ if we rewrite the old definition as $f_X(M)=\sqrt{\operatorname{trace}(XMM^H)}$. (For Hermitian matrices, $M=M^H$ and hence the definition remains unchanged.) This is actually the Frobenius norm of $X^{1/2}M$. So, it is a norm on $M_n(\mathbb R)$ (and on the set of all real symmetric matrices in particular).

However, $f_X$ is not necessarily submultiplicative. For instance, let $X=c^2I$, so that $f_X(M)=c\|M\|_F$. Since the value of every submultiplicative matrix norm of $M=I$ must be at least $1$, $f_X$ is not submultiplicative when $0<c<1$.

In general, $f_X$ is submultiplicative if and only if all eigenvalues of $X$ are greater than or equal to $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not looking for sub-multiplicativity. So I am guessing the second part of the question is true too that the dual norm is the one corresponding to X^{-1}.

Comment: @user1189053 Yes, the dual norm is $f_{X^{-1}}$.

Comment: it isn't a norm on $M_n$. There are plenty matrices $M\ne 0$ such $M^2 = 0$! It is only a norm on symmetric / hermitian matrices!

Comment: $M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \ne 0$ but $M^2 = 0$ thus $f_X(M) = 0$ thus $f_X$ is not positive definite.

Comment: however OP ask for symmetric matrices only. so basically no harm.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks. When M is not Hermitian, $f_X(M)$ should be defined as the square root of the trace of $XMM^H$. It's my fault that I haven't made this clear.